# How many roots does a polynomial in 2 variables have?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

We know that in general a polynomial in one variable of degree n has n roots. What about in two variables?

It seems instead of discrete points we have whole regions. For example:

$xy = 0$ has as solutions the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis.

How about higher degree/more complicated polynomials in two variables?

Comment: A quick note: while it's somewhat difficult to formulate this question precisely over, say, $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, it's a lot easier over finite fields, where there are finitely many points and so one just needs to count them. The relevant statement is the [Schwartz--Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma), which says that if $f\in \mathbb F_q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an $n$-variable polynomial of degree $d$ over $\mathbb F_q$, it has at most $dq^{n-1}$ zeros. That is, its "density of zeros" is at most $d/q$, the same bound as in the one-variable case.

Comment: You've touched upon what turns out to be a vast and challenging area of mathematics. You are correct in your observations that for polynomials in more than one variable, its zero set (or roots) can have much more complicated structure. Generically, such zero sets will be surfaces (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and thus there will be an infinite number of roots. This will continue to be true for degree greater than $2$. The zero set of a polynomial is called an *algebraic variety*, and studying these objects are a motivating goal for *algebraic geometry*. Needless to say, this is a complicated subject.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say a single-variable polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, let us first discuss the complex case. In $\mathbf{C}^d$ with $d > 1$, a single polynomial of degree $n > 0$ always has infinitely many zeros, and the set of zeros (often called a *hypersurface*) is always $d - 1$ dimensional for an appropriate sense of dimension (for example, near "most" of its points it looks like $\mathbf{C}^{d-1}$). That it has infinitely many solutions is not so hard to see by induction on $d$, essentially all but finitely many values of $x_d$ will keep the polynomial non-constant, and then it must have zeros.

In $\mathbf{R}^d$ the situation is not as uniform. For example in $\mathbf{R}^2$, the polynomial
$$((x-a_1)^2 + (y-b_1)^2) \dotsm ((x-a_r)^2 + (y - b_r)^2)$$
has exactly $r$ zeros $(a_i, b_i)$, and you already have examples where the set of zeros is infinite. Using a similar idea, and depending on your definition of dimension, the set of zeros of a (non-constant) polynomial in $\mathbf{R}^d$ can have dimension any integer from $0$ to $d-1$.

The case of finite fields (where of course the set of zeros has to be finite) was summarized in a comment by Carl Schildkraut. For other infinite fields the definition of dimension is more complicated (or at least different than what I wrote above) but depending on whether the field is algebraically closed then the situation is similar to that of $\mathbf{C}$ or $\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score -4):

The degree of a polynomial's term is the sum of the exponents for all variables in that term.  So I'd find which term in the polynomial has a maximum exponent sum for all variables and that's the polynomial's degree, which the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says has that many roots.  (I think - 95% sure but not 100% sure.)

Comment: Have you tried the simplest examples?

Comment: Consider $x^2+y^2-1=0$. A circle does not have only $2$ points.